# Excel Return Value Based On Date Comparison

Tags: excel, date

I have a table that has the release dates and version of a product:

```
Version,    Release Date
7   9/15/2000
8   8/19/2002
9   9/8/2003
10  8/30/2004
11  8/8/2005
12  8/15/2006
13  6/5/2007
14  12/1/2009
15  3/18/2015
```

I want to return the latest version that was available given an example date. For example, if a cell had `2/28/2017`, I want it to return `15`, because Version 15 was the last version out as of Feb 28, 2017. But for `2/28/2010`, I would have it return `14` because 14 was the latest version available as of February 28, 2010.

I was thinking of using `index` and `match` but I am unsure of how to make it return the latest version.

Edit: Here is what I have tried but once again, I don't know how to make it return the latest date. `F2` contains the date I am comparing (February 28, 2010 for this example)

```
{=IF($F$2>B2:B11,B2:B11)}
```

Excel evaluates this as `IF(TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE},B2:B11)` but this will return `9/15/2000`. I want to return the row corresponding to the last `TRUE`

Comment: I'll think about this to come up with a solution. Are you opposed to a VBA function? I could write that in 5 minutes. Also, why Excel instead of a database? This would be an easy SQL statement.

Comment: I am looking to keep it simple and just stick to Formulas. The file will be shared with other individuals so I wouldn't want to send them VBA code as well.

Comment: @findwindow: Just did.

Comment: Er, not good with formulas but wrap it in `max`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. I setup my Excel just like yours so as long as your data starts in A2. Headers in Row 1.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$10, MATCH(DATEVALUE("2/28/2010"), $B$2:$B$10,1), 1 )
```

But if you pass in a date that is in another cell (E1 for this example) you can skip the `DATEVALUE()` function like this

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$10, MATCH(E1, $B$2:$B$10,1), 1 )
```

The key to this solution is the last param for the `MATCH` function. It's a 1 for "Less Than".

**Disclaimer**
As @ScottCraner pointed out, this formula only works if the dates are sorted ascending.

Comment: Please accept this if it worked for you. I'm still trying to build my reputation.

Comment: @Bijan you know how it is to earn reputation :)

Comment: Accepted and voted yours! Thanks for the answer, I used second part without `Datevalue` since Date comes from a cell

Comment: @Bijan FWIW this only works if the dates are always in Ascending order.  It is a great answer if this is always the case.  If not you will need an array formula.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. You're clearly a smart person with 2400 rep. I'm sure you could teach me a lot as well and I'll probably see you answer some of my questions :)

Comment: I should have mentioned that. I assumed becuase of this setup that they would always be ascending. Thanks for pointing this out @ScottCraner, I'll edit my post to mention that.